# Parameter cause a table scan in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have two tables a, b, primary key is their index.

**Requirement:**

If `@filter` is empty, select all records of a, b, else split `@filter` by any specific separator, find records whose `b.PKey` are in the filter.

Current Implementation:

```
declare @filter nvarchar(max)= ''

SELECT * 
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.PKey = b.aPKey
       AND (@filter = '' OR b.PKey IN (SELECT item FROM splitFunction(@filter))
```

I found the last statement `and (@filter = '' or b.PKey in (select item from splitFunction(@filter))` will always cause a table scan on table b, only if I remove `@filter=''`, it will change to index seek.

Is there any way can implement my requirement and does not harm the performance?

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500/do-indexes-work-with-in-clause

Comment: @AbdulRasheed, thanks, it helps but seems not the same issue. My question is the join condition `@filter=''` cause a table scan. If I remove it, index will be used.

Comment: Relevant: [Dynamic Search Conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Comment: Firstly I suggest that your `AND` part is not a join condition it's a `WHERE` condition. Functionally there isn't any difference between putting it in ON or WHERE, but since the expression is not evaluating a match between two tables, to me it's a where condition. It would make a difference if it was an outer join but since it's an inner join it won't

Comment: Your actual issue might be incorrect query plan cached, or parameter sniffing .If you use `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` as per here, does performance improve: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For constants, the optimizer can work out the best plan based on statistics for the given values.

When you use variable you are forcing parameterization and the plan will be designed to be reusable for a wide range of values. So Optimizer uses scan and not seek. To overcome this problem stop using local variables in the query and use this as a parameter in stored procedure

```
create procedure p1
@filter = ''
as
begin
SELECT * 
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.PKey = b.aPKey
       AND (@filter = '' OR b.PKey IN (SELECT item FROM splitFunction(@filter))
option (recompile)
end
```

This will give you the correct plan as in the stored procedure I have converted your local variable into parameter.

Comment: Yes, it works! But I still have doubt on that, if this is caused by the optimizer, why this statement does NOT work? `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR (@filter=''))`

Comment: Option optimize for is not working because @filter is a local variable and when execution plan is been made optimizer does not know its value and takes rough estimates. That is the reason why your option optimize is not working . If you use the same in stored procedure it will work

Comment: I did this actually in stored procedure, it didn't work:( . Once changed to `option(recompile)`, it works again.

Comment: Now Optimize for means that optimizer will create plan taking the option filter ='' and this means it has to return all the values. Even when filter <> '' still optimizer will make the plan for filter = ''. So you will always get scans. Optimize for is helpfull when number of rows are static and will not change. In your case number of rows as output varies depending in the value of filter. Scan when filter = '' and seek when filter <> ''. For more infrmation refer to the link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714%28SQL.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for this case, you can also try this:

```
DECLARE @filter nvarchar(max)= ''

IF @filter = ''
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM a
    JOIN b ON a.PKey = b.aPKey
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM a
    JOIN b ON a.PKey = b.aPKey
    WHERE b.PKey IN (SELECT item FROM splitFunction(@filter))
END
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But here my question is an example that can explain clearly. If we have multiple tables and multiple filters. This way seems doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple tables then this will not result in the most optimal solution. That's why I mentioned specifically for this case.